# Calling a function defined inside a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I'm using Angular 1.2 and have a function defined inside a directive:

```
.directive(
'Derp',
function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$parent.sum = function() {
                //something
            }
        })
}
})
```

I'm calling that function from my main controller like this:

```
$scope.sum();
```

But I'm getting this error in the browser console:

```
TypeError: $scope.sum is not a function
```

Am I getting something wrong?

Comment: You defined the function within the scope of the directive, not the main controller; hence, the reason it cannot find it. Is there a reason why you are defining the function here, rather than say in the main controller?

Comment: Yes I need to leave the function inside the directive because of a library I'm using. Anyway I edited the code above because I forgot the "$parent" inside the function definition. My bad.

Comment: Relying on the hierarchy of scopes is a faulty pattern that isn't considered a 'best practice' currently. The exact solution depends on how the directive and `sum` are used.

Answer (score 0):

bind it to scope in your link function.

just access it like `ng-click="sum()"`

```
link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
  // Scope Variables
  scope.sum = sum;

  function sum(){
    //something
  }
}
```